# Calling a Selenium Python Script from PHP

Tags: php, python, firefox, selenium

I am tying to call a python Selenium webdriver script from PHP and I keep getting the following error:

"Traceback (most recent call last): File "seltest.py", line 12, in setUp self.driver = webdriver.Firefox() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in **init** self.binary, timeout), File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in **init** self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 64, in launch_browser self._wait_until_connectable() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 103, in _wait_until_connectable self._get_firefox_output()) WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: None'"

The python script works just fine when running it from the command line.

Content of test.php:

```
        <?php    
           $test = `python seltest.py 2>&1`;
           var_dump ($test);    
        ?>
```

Content of seltest.py:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
    import unittest, time, re

    class Seltext(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
            self.verificationErrors = []
            self.accept_next_alert = True

        def test_seltext(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get(self.base_url + "/?gws_rd=ssl")
            driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").clear()
            driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq").send_keys("what is selenium webdriver")
            driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfb").click()

        def is_element_present(self, how, what):
            try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
            except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
            return True

        def is_alert_present(self):
            try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
            return True

        def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
            try:
                alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
                alert_text = alert.text
                if self.accept_next_alert:
                    alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I have all ready confirmed that the user for the web server has permission to run the python script.  I have even tried to run the web server as my user and group and still no luck.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 12.04 with Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14, Selenium 2.43.0, and Python 2.7.3.

Comment: The big question will be WHY!?

Comment: This is part of a big project with the end result of walking through a web page to find a PDF link, send the PDF link back to the PHP script to download and scrap information out of the PDF.

Comment: Then I will give you best answer ever when trying to mix technologies, and to get it you have to picture fameous opening speech by Steve Blamer. Messaging systems, messaging systems, messaging systems, messaging systems, messaging systems.
This is your solution when you need to chain events, even more so when doing that across many technologies.

Comment: just give the permission 777 to the ghostdriver.log. hopefully it will work. :)

Comment: fix the indentation errors first